# What web server should I install?

Tags: php, webserver

I have Windows 7 Enterprise and I want to run a web server on this computer and I wander what is the best web server would be in my case. I have several requirements to the web server.

1. It should be easy to install and set up the server. Just "click", "accept" and that's it.
2. It should support MySQL and PHP (with GET, POST, SESSION, and cookies).
3. I want to be able to install the server from CD or memory stick. In other words, I want to be able to download something on my CD and than use this CD to install the web server.
4. The server (software) should not occupy a lot of memory.
5. It should be possible to install the web server on Linux, Windows and MAC.

Comment: You already have IIS7 installed, so points 1 to 4 are covered, but point 5 eliminates it :)

Comment: This is interesting that I have already the IIS7. How can I run it? I just tried to open my IP address in my browser and it did not worked.

Comment: Laykes, what is wrong with the IIS?

Comment: @Roman: IIS is a "service".  Check your control panels to start it.

Comment: @Roman: Here's what @Laykes is talking about: http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/02/05/iis-vs-apache-in-pictures/

Answer (score 7):

Install [Z-WAMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zwamp/files/). It has the latest versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP (with APC and phyMyAdmin). It's also portable so you can have it installed on a mem stick.

Comment: I have used XAMPP for years which is nice but I have always wanted something more like Z-WAMP.  It is PERFECT

Answer (score 3):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is very simple to install and use.

Comment: I'm running XAMPP on my MacBook very happily, and I've also had it running on Windows machines in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting:

> [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) is a fast and reliable PHP application stack. It is completely free, and you can use it in development, testing and production.

Further:

> Eliminate wasted time spent on putting together your PHP stack piece by piece.  Zend Server Community Edition includes everything you need, whether you’re using Windows, Linux or Mac OS X. The simple, native installers will set you up in minutes with:
>
> - Bytecode accelerator (Optimizer+)
> - Zend Data Cache
> - A certified PHP distribution
> - Zend Framework
> - Apache (or IIS integration)
> - MySQL (on Windows and Mac OS X)
> - Out-of-the-box connectivity to all common databases
> - Java code connectivity
> - Web-based PHP administrator console

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you mean but take a look at [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) it installs Apache, PHP and MySQL for you with one installation file.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine requirement 1, 3 and 5 you make it extremely difficult.

There is not just one package that you can install on boot *nix and windows. Simply because they use a different Operating System with other drive mappings, libraries, etc.

But for Windows I recommend one of the XAMP/WAMP implementation (I'm not a Windows User). For Mac there is MAMP. On other *nix based systems I always used predefined packages or a manualy compiled amount of packages which does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Latest OSX has buildin PHP and Apache. You only have to enable Apache in your system pref panel. MySQL can be installed.

It's also possible to use XAMPP for osx. Can be installed from CD

As for Windows you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). This package includes Apache, PHP and MySQL. Can be installed from CD.

Most Linux distro's have apache build in. And it's easy to configure PHP and MySQL for it. You can also use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) for linux:

Answer (score 0):

LAMP for linux
XAMPP for mac
and WAMP for win
Different gui almost the same thing easy to setup and configure.

Answer (score 0):

The big advantages with [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php) are that you can easily switch PHP/Apache/MySQL version and toggle PHP settings + extensions, directly from the taskbar.

That's why I'm using it.

Note: Even though you can't download the latest PHP version from their site, [it's very easy to install it yourself](http://markushedlund.com/dev-tech/install-php-5.3.3-on-wamp).